# Get UITextView dynamic height with auto layout after setting text

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uitextview

I have a UITextView not scrollable with auto layout set by interface builder, and the text increase or decrease dynamically with no problem, but i want know what is the new UITextView height after setting text, i'm trying to do this:

```
NSLog(@"text before: %.2f",self.myText.frame.size.height);
[self.myText setText:self.string];
NSLog(@"text after: %.2f",self.myText.frame.size.height);
```

this is the result:

```
text before: 47.50
text after: 47.50
```

the text is increased in the view when i run it, but the size is the same, how i can get the real height after setting text?

Comment: I am facing a issue where my textview does not grow larger to accomodate bigger texts, could you please share the steps you followed to achieve this?

Comment: relevant: `TextViewHeightConstraint.constant = [TextView intrinsicContentSize].height`  Also don't forget to uncheck scrolling!!

Comment: This has been answered in the link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56156621/6386213

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work:

```
NSLog(@"text before: %.2f",self.myText.frame.size.height);
[self.myText setText:self.string];
[self.myText layoutIfNeeded]; // <--- Add this
NSLog(@"text after: %.2f",self.myText.frame.size.height);
```

Here's an example implementation on my Github: https://github.com/guillaume-algis/SO-27060338

Comment: Just tested, works for me. I put an example on my Github: https://github.com/guillaume-algis/SO-27060338

Answer (score 96):

All you have to do is:

- set up all your constraints except *the height one* **AND**
- set `textView`'s `scrollEnabled` property to `NO`

The last part is what does the trick.

Your text view will size automatically depending on its text value.

Comment: This doesn't work for me: The entered text is invisible, and after entering several lines it finally appears at the bottom!

Comment: Forget it: adding `textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)` fixed it.

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 34):

If you prefer to do it all by auto layout:

In Size Inspector:

1. Set **Content Compression Resistance Priority Vertical** to 1000.
2. Lower the priority of constraint height for your UITextView. Just make it less than 1000.

[image]

In Attributes Inspector:

1. Uncheck **Scrolling Enabled**.

Comment: It works perfectly, otherwise all the above codes doesn't work in my case. Thank you.

Comment: Yes this method is working perfectly. I use this idea in coding design part.

Answer (score 13):

I have used the code given on following link [AutoLayout with Dynamic UITextView height](http://imnotyourson.com/autolayout-with-dynamic-uitextview-height/) and it worked for me :)

Comment: This is a link-only answer, could you summarize the contents of the link in your answer?

Comment: This is working for my message designing. but I need only increase for four lines after the four lin. textView stop the height increase and scroll. anyone knowns please answer or share the link.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 3.0**

```
textView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

This allow AutoLayout to do its job.

Comment: That's essentially the only thing that's needed. I've added the textView in Interface builder, so I had to uncheck the "Scrolling Enabled" in IB in identity inspector of the `UITextView`. Also, the only constraints I've added were the top, leading and trailing. So that the height was not defined by constraints, those allowing the size to change automatically.

Answer (score 7):

Use below code:

Objective-C Code

```
[textView setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

Swift Code

```
textView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Comment: It's isScrollEnabled now. Couldn't edit because it's too small of an edit

Comment: Thanks for the suggession, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just after changing the text call

```
[self.myText sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike UILabel, UITextView's has no intrinsic size property. So how I did it was set up the `UITextView`'s height constraint, hook it via IBOutlet, and change its value in `textViewDidChange` or when text changes.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

    // dynamic height adjustments

    var height = ceil(textView.contentSize.height) // ceil to avoid decimal

    if height != textViewHeight.constant { // set when height changed
        textViewHeight.constant = height
        textView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: false) // scroll to top to avoid "wrong contentOffset" artefact when line count changes
    }
}
```

Comment: but when you typing you should see end of the text. scroll to bottom with next line of code: textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: textHeight - textView.bounds.size.height), animated: true)

Comment: @RomanFilippov It's a bit trickier than that though. You could be moving the text input cursor to the top and and add new text there. Which means new text can be added anywhere. I guess one missing piece is detecting where the text is inserted and scroll to there instead, which can be top, or bottom, or somewhere in the center.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    UIFont *myFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    CGSize size =   [self sizeOfText:textView.text widthOfTextView:TextviewWidth withFont:myFont];
    NSLog(@"Height : %f", size.height);
}

-(CGSize)sizeOfText:(NSString *)textToMesure widthOfTextView:(CGFloat)width withFont:(UIFont*)font
{
    CGSize ts = [textToMesure sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width-20.0, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    return ts;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

select textview and uncheck "Scrolling enabled"

select textview from top menu "Editor > size to fit content"

select the view below it, set its **top constraints** with the **textview bottom** to whatever margin you want, then go to "Size Inspector",double click or edit the constraint you just added, and set the "Relation" to "Greater than or Equal"

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach is to use

```
myTextView.textContainer.heightTracksTextView = true
```

Which allows scroll to be enabled

Answer (score 1):

Well, I haven't converted this code into swift4 syntax, but the logic will remain the same. This is an extension method for Xamarin.ios(C#).

```
public static nfloat GetEstimateHeight(this UITextView textView, UIView View)
{
    var size = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(View.Frame.Width, height: float.PositiveInfinity);
    var estimatedSize = textView.SizeThatFits(size);
    return estimatedSize.Height;
}
```

The logic here that will work for swift is

```
var size = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(View.Frame.Width, height: float.PositiveInfinity);
    var estimatedSize = textView.SizeThatFits(size);
    var textViewFinalHeight = estimatedSize.Height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition as per @Pavel Gurov's answer. If you already set up your height constraint, simply make it inactive. Also worth to call `.sizeToFit()` afterwards to make sure resize action is performed.

```swift
theTextViewHeightConstraint.isActive = false

theTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
theTextView.text = "some text"
theTextView.sizeToFit()
```

Answer (score 0):

the textview height increase by using pure swift code design. I am just do coding part only.

I take this idea from
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45071002/9110213

First thing create the textView

```
    import UIKit
    
    class TextFieldCell: UITableViewCell {
        
        lazy var btnEdit: UIButton! = {
          
          let button = UIButton()
          button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
          button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.actionEdit(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
          button.setTitle("Edit", for: .normal)
          button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "ProximaNova-Medium", size: 18)
          button.setTitleColor( UIColor(red: 0.29, green: 0.56, blue: 0.89, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
          button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .left
          return button
          
        }()
      
      lazy var separatorView: UIView! = {
        
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
        
      }()
      
      lazy var textView: UITextView! = {
        
        let textView = UITextView.init(frame: .zero)
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.delegate = self
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        return textView
        
      }()
      
      lazy var titleLabel: UILabel! = {
        
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 27, y: 318, width: 27, height: 12))
        label.text = "Name"
        label.font = UIFont(name: "ProximaNova-Medium", size: 10)
        label.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.61, green: 0.61, blue: 0.61, alpha: 1)
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
        
      }()
        
      
      deinit {
        self.titleLabel = nil
        self.textView = nil
        self.separatorView = nil
        self.btnEdit = nil
      }
        
      override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        self.selectionStyle = .none
        
        self.addView()
        self.setConstraint()
        
      }
      
      required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
      }
      
    }
    
    extension TextFieldCell {
    
      func addView(){
        
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.btnEdit)
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.titleLabel)
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.textView)
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.separatorView)
    
      }
      
      func setConstraint(){
        
       // This part is very important to increase the textview height dyamically   

        let textViewHeight = self.textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 27)
        textViewHeight.priority = .defaultHigh
        self.textView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        self.textView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
    
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
          
          self.titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 27),
          self.titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 38),
          
          self.textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 9),
          self.textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.titleLabel.leadingAnchor),
          textViewHeight,
          self.textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.btnEdit.leadingAnchor, constant: -25),
    
          self.btnEdit.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.textView.centerYAnchor),
          self.btnEdit.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
          self.btnEdit.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -33),
          
          self.separatorView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.textView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
          self.separatorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1),
          self.separatorView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor),
          self.separatorView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 27),
          self.separatorView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -15),
          
        ])
        
      }
      
    }
    
    extension TextFieldCell {
    
         @objc func actionEdit(_ sender: UIButton) {
            
        }
      
    }
    
    extension TextFieldCell: UITextViewDelegate {
      func notifyViewController(text:String){
        
      }
      func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        
      }
    }
```